# Ошибка в SQL запросе(С#)

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, uwp

Добрый день.

Есть JSON я его пишу в БД.

Стоит задача проверить есть ли  в базе данных поля, если есть просто обновить, если появилось новое значение дописать его,  если таблица пустая, то записать значения.

Json пишу так

```
 public class Billing
    {
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string company { get; set; }
        public string address_1 { get; set; }
        public string address_2 { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string postcode { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
    }

    public class Shipping
    {
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string company { get; set; }
        public string address_1 { get; set; }
        public string address_2 { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string postcode { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int parent_id { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string order_key { get; set; }
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public string version { get; set; }
        public bool prices_include_tax { get; set; }
        public string date_created { get; set; }
        public string date_modified { get; set; }
        public int customer_id { get; set; }
        public double discount_total { get; set; }
        public double discount_tax { get; set; }
        public double shipping_total { get; set; }
        public double shipping_tax { get; set; }
        public double cart_tax { get; set; }
        public double total { get; set; }
        public double total_tax { get; set; }
        public Billing billing { get; set; }
        public Shipping shipping { get; set; }
        public string payment_method { get; set; }
        public string payment_method_title { get; set; }
        public string transaction_id { get; set; }
        public string customer_ip_address { get; set; }
        public string customer_user_agent { get; set; }
        public string created_via { get; set; }
        public string customer_note { get; set; }
        public string date_completed { get; set; }
        public string date_paid { get; set; }
        public string cart_hash { get; set; }
        public List<object> line_items { get; set; }
        public List<object> tax_lines { get; set; }
        public List<object> shipping_lines { get; set; }
        public List<object> fee_lines { get; set; }
        public List<object> coupon_lines { get; set; }
    }

 public async void Down()
    {







        RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("http://simplegames.com.ua/wp-json/wc/v1/", "ck_9d64c027d2c5f81b8bed3342eeccc6d337be813d", "cs_60697b1e6cbdeb8d62d19e0765e339f8e3334754");
        WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);
        //Get all products
        var orders = await wc.GetOrders(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
            { "per_page", "100" }});




        string products = orders.ToFormattedJsonString();

        List<RootObject> rootObjectData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(products);


        foreach (RootObject root in rootObjectData)
        {
            int id = root.id;
            int customer_id = root.customer_id;

            string fio = root.billing.first_name + " " + "  " + root.billing.last_name;
            string adress = root.billing.address_1 + " " + "  " + root.billing.address_2;
            double total = root.total;
```

Пытаюсь делать проверку и апдейт так

```
 using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Database= milanoold_db;Data Source=144.76.133.122;User Id=*********;Password=********; SslMode=None; CharSet=utf8"))
            {
                // Открытие соединения
                connection.Open();
                using (MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = "if exists(select 183 from orders where id =@id) begin update orders set customer_id = @customer_id, total = @total, fio = @fio, adress = @adress where id = @id end else begin insert into orders (id, customer_id, total, fio, adress) values(@id, @customer_id, @total, @fio, @adress) end";
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer_id", customer_id);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", total);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fio", fio);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adress", adress);
                    connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Close();
                }
```

Выдает такую вот ошибку `Additional information: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if exists(select 1983 from orders where id =1943) begin update orders set custom' at line 1`

Вопрос, как это можно пофиксить или как переписать код, так, чтобы оно выполняло поставленную задачу.

Comment: Кто - то знает как решить проблему?

Comment: Пароль, надеюсь, ненастоящий?

Answer (score 1):

Решение проблемы найдено

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Database= milanoold_db;Data Source=144.76.133.122;User Id=milanoold_u;Password=sK5PvCDP; SslMode=None; CharSet=utf8"))
                    {
                        // Открытие соединения

                        using (MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                        {
                            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO orders (id,customer_id,total,fio,adress) VALUES(@id, @customer_id, @total, @fio, @adress) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = @id,customer_id = @customer_id,total = @total,fio = @fio,adress = @adress;";
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer_id", customer_id);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", total);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fio", fio);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adress", adress);
                            connection.Open();
                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            connection.Close();
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Советую сменить пользователя и пароль и больше не светить в открытый доступ ;)